# Rooting An HTC desire bravo Phone

Tags: rooting

help me to root my htc desire bravo
configrations are: 
bravo pvt3 ship s-on 
h.boot -0.83.0001
microp-051d 
radio- 5.09.05.30_2
help me and give me the easiest mehtod i tried revolutionary it says that your hboot version is not supported 
i have android2.2 foryo